# how to extend a class that uses destructuring constructor in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, google-maps-api-3, webgloverlayview

My question is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40433555/typescript-class-inheritance-constructor-confusion) but the class I am trying to extend accepts an object parameter.

here is the class I want to extend:

```
    class ThreeJSOverlayView implements google.maps.WebglOverlayView {

    constructor({
      anchor = { lat: 0, lng: 0, altitude: 0 },
      rotation = new Float32Array([0, 0, 0]),
      scale = new Float32Array([1, 1, 1]),
      scene = new Scene(),
      map,
    }: ThreeJSOverlayViewOptions) {
    //body of constructor...
   }
    //rest of code
 }
```

I am extending the class just to add the following method that lets me read some values(camera) that are protected by the original class.

```
getCameraMatrices():Matrix4{
    return this.camera.projectionMatrix;
}
```

I have tried extending the class without implementing the constructor, but it didn't work. I tried the following but it didn't work

```
export class CustomeThreeOverlay extends ThreeJSOverlayView{
constructor(options: ThreeJSOverlayViewOptions){
    super(options)
}
getCameraMatrices():Matrix4{
    return this.camera.projectionMatrix;
}
```

}

You can find the full code for the class I am trying to extend [here](https://github.com/googlemaps/js-three/blob/main/src/three.ts)

Comment: What does “didn't work” actually mean? An error occurred or the behavior is not what you expected?
And looks like from language perspective there is no difference between using `super` and removing `constructor` at all (as it will do the same by default).

Comment: @AndreyProgr no error. but when using the original class, scene gets rendered but when using my customer class scene is not rendered. so yes the behavior is difrent

Comment: Hmm, not sure, but there may be some problems with context (`this`) in such a case.

Comment: @AndreyProgr it worked when I changed the target in tsconfig from es5 to es6. but I want it to work on most browsers so I want the target to be es5.